# JLabels created from an ArrayList<String> won't appear * when others will *

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I am not new to GUI or swing programming, just as a disclaimer.

In my class that extends JPanel, I have an ArrayList< String > opponentNames that I want to use to create JLabels. I have an ArrayList<  JLabel > labels to contain the JLabels. I used this list and also I tried to add directly to the frame which is why both are in the code block below. I know that I should just use one.

```
for(String s : opponentNames){
   JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
   label.setVisible(true);
   labels.add(label);
   this.add(label);
}
```

Then later on I added test JLabels in the same exact manner without using my ArrayList < String >:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   JLabel label = new JLabel(""+i);
   label.setVisible(true);
   labels.add(label);
   this.add(label);
}
```

This adds 5 JLabels to my panel.

Later on I tried adding all of ArrayList < JLabel > labels again to the panel:

```
for(JLabel l : labels){
   System.out.println(l.getText());
   System.out.println(l.isVisible());
   this.add(l);
}
```

In the console, every single label prints out with the proper text (the numbers and the Strings from ArrayList < String> opponentNames) **but** the only things that appear on the screen are the JLabels 0...4, twice.

TL;DR: All of my JLabels exist and are set visible, but only some are appearing on the screen.

edit: I had a typo: is supposed to be label.setVisible(true); in the first for loop. This code here is not copied and pasted, it is greatly simplified. That was/is not the error in my code.

edit2: Here is runnable code. Of course when I tested it my problem isn't happening here, so that tells me that there is an issue elsewhere in my code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JLabelTestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestJLabelCode panel = new TestJLabelCode();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setContentPane(panel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.validate();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
}

}
```

Then the other class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestJLabelCode extends JPanel{
private ArrayList<String> opponentNames;
private ArrayList<JLabel> labels;


public TestJLabelCode(){
    opponentNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    opponentNames.add("client1");
    opponentNames.add("client2");
    opponentNames.add("client3");
    opponentNames.add("client4");
    opponentNames.add("client5");

    for(String s : opponentNames){
        JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
        label.setVisible(true);
        labels.add(label);
        this.add(label);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        JLabel label = new JLabel(""+i);
        label.setVisible(true);
        labels.add(label);
        this.add(label);
    }

    for(JLabel label : labels){
        System.out.println(label.getText());
        System.out.println(label.isVisible());

        add(label);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please create and post a [minimal example program](http://sscce.org) so we can experience your error first hand. I'm thinking that your layout managers and possible setting sizes or preferred sizes will be key to your error.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will write one right now, thank you

Comment: Whenever I see a question where someone wants to create and display a collection of JLabels, I think to myself -- could a JList work better here? You should consider this yourself as you create your [minimal runnable example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I think your error lies elsewhere in your code, because after your edit this code looks fine to me. The only thing I don't understand is, why you add all those labels again, so add them twice. That may cause trouble.

Comment: Yes, your latest code runs fine, meaning that you still have debugging to do to try to isolate your error. As an aside, most all those `setVisible(true)` are completely unnecessary. The only one needed is the one on the JFrame. Also -- are you loading the JLabels as the program is running? If so, do you `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the container that is receiving them?

Comment: @Zhedar i mentioned that in a note above, it was to test if there was an issue with creating an arraylist of jlabels and then iterating through the arraylist to add them to the panel. you're right that the error must be elsewhere but i am totally stumped because the console prints all of the jlabels' text and prints that they are all visible, but then only some are displayed. thank you very much for taking a loot at this

Answer (score 0):

I assume `this`, so your class, extends `JFrame` (or another Swing container, like a `JPanel`) and that's why you use `this.add()`.
In the first for loop, you add the `String s` to your frame, not the `JLabel`.
It should be

```
for(String s : opponentNames){
   JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
   label.setVisible(true);
   labels.add(label);
   this.add(label);
}
```

instead of

```
for(String s : opponentNames){
       JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
       s.setVisible(true);
       labels.add(s);
       this.add(s);
    }
```

Your current code shouldn't even compile, since `String` doesn't contain a method `setVisible(boolean)` and if your `ArrayList` is generic and thus only takes `JLabel`s.

Comment: This is not direct code, and this class extends JPanel. I then add this JPanel to my JFrame. (Actually I add it to another JPanel and then set the contentPane of that JFrame).

Comment: Your code shown here won't compile, what do you mean by "this is not direct code"?

Comment: I didn't copy and paste this code, this is a small segment from a massive networked game of Pente. I wrote it here to illustrate the issue. I'm about to post real code

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of my error. This is a very small piece of a very large networked game. I accidentally created this panel twice. I was repainting the first instance of it, which was initialized without client/opponent names, even though I was properly updating the second instance of it. The print statements in the console were coming from the second instance, while the first instance was the only one displayed.

Thank you to @HovercraftFullOfEels and @Zhedar for your help.

Comment: How did you work this out? I am having a very similar problem and believe this is the cause, but I have no idea how to fix it or how to work it out.